# Error in backup of MySQL from Java

Tags: java

I have developed a Java application and it's in last stage.

The problem is that I cannot execute the mysqldump with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

```
try {
    String[] command = new String[] {
        "cmd.exe",
        "/c",
        "mysqldump --host=" + host + " --user=" + dbuser + " --password=" + dbpass + " " + dbname + " > " + filename
    };
    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    int ProcessComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
    if (ProcessComplete == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database backup has been done successfully");
    }
    else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database backup was unsuccessfull");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, command);
    }
}
catch (IOException | InterruptedException exc) {
    Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, exc);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: *Can't execute* in what way? What happens? What do you expect to happen instead? Is there an exception? On which line?

Comment: i got the solution buddy....very long back...thanks for asking'

Comment: i just created a bat file and did it..

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in Windows and it works fine for me.

Open `cmd`, type `mysqldump` and hit enter.

If it is executed successfully, that means your code should work properly if your database configuration is correct.

If you get `'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command` then either you have to set the MySQL path in your environment variable, or specify the full path for `mysqldump` in your Java code like this:

```
String[] command  = new String[] {
    "cmd.exe",
    "/c",
    "c://mysql/bin/mysqldump --host=" + host + " --user=" + dbuser + " --password=" + dbpass + " " + dbname + " > " + filename
};
```